# Filter cells by value and column index

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I searched the web and previous stackoverflow questions and couldn't find a good answer, so I would appreciate your help.

I have a pd.df =

```
           12         13         14         15   ...        141        142
12    0.000000   3.856802   5.442729   7.637788  ...  31.144092  34.277933   
13    3.856802   0.000000   3.825300   4.735988  ...  29.098527  32.350149   
14    5.442729   3.825300   0.000000   3.817564  ...  25.837813  29.062540   
15    7.637788   4.735988   3.817564   0.000000  ...  25.712116  29.186678   
16   10.947102   8.529696   6.548704   3.853627  ...  23.226639  26.856628   
17   12.473594  10.760961   7.616927   6.705854  ...  20.499088  4.051315
```

where the indexes continue as well, to about 140.

These are distances, and I want to find cells with distances smaller than 6 and also farther than 5 positions away.

So the cell `[16, 15]`, even though it is smaller than 6, doesn't interest me, but [17, 142] does.

I can easily find the close cells using:

`neighbors = df < 6`

to get an array of True and False, which I can sum:

`neighbors.sum(axis=1)`

Currently, when I sum this way I get a series like this where sum =

```
12     3
13     4
.
.
.
138    5
139    3
140    6
141    4
142    4
143    5
```

I would like to have this same output, just with only including in the sum the cells that comply to the rule (cell with data smaller than 6 but indexes that are far (larger than 5 difference)).

Thanks anyone who can offer ideas!

Comment: post the code that you have tried

Comment: Please share expected output.